# php symfony2 login_check captcha

Tags: php

I have authentication and authorisation working fine in my php/symfony2 project. Now I am trying to add recaptcha on the user creation and login. I have it working on the user creation, but the login posts to login_check and ignores the captcha.
How can I add the captcha validation on login?
Thanks

Comment: really?  You're going to annoy your users every time you want them to log in by adding a captcha.  You've already used it for registration isn't that good enough?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/excelwebzone/EWZRecaptchaBundle) is a bundle that will generate a captcha for you.